# Android : How does one uninstall a wear watch face from the emulator?

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I'm looking to uninstall a custom watch face from a running emulator without resorting to wiping the emulator and rebooting.  Which ADB commands might I send to the emulator to perform this task?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like any Android device, you can use [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). From a command line:

```
adb uninstall com.your.package.name
```

If multiple devices are connected, get their names with `adb devices` and then use:

```
adb -s device-name uninstall com.your.package.name
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, you can also delete a face from a watch as follows

1. Hook your host phone via usd to a computer with Android SDK
2. execute adb in shell mode `adb shell`
3. `pm uninstall com.your.package_name`

This will remove the package from the phone **and** the watch
Ideal for situations where you messed your APK signature leaving package name unchanged.